# Laravel 5.2.26 get form validation data array

Tags: validation, laravel

[image: How to get form validation return data array on signup form]

I submit the form and have some validation mean email,require,unique email,

when validation have error message then laravel 5.2 return validation return array.

Comment: Can you show me how exactly do you get this object please?

Comment: when any one submit form and empty the userName or email 

then I will create validation in controller. 

if user have no userName and email 

validation return error array

and also form data 

i need form data

Comment: Why don't you just use request data?

Comment: I am new in laravel please help how to use request data ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to retain the submitted data on error.

Considering a sample

```
public function postJobs(Request $request) {
    $input     = $request->all(); 

    $messages  = [
        'job_title.required'      => trans('job.title_required'),
    ];        

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'job_title'    => 'required'
    ], $messages);       

    if ($validator->fails()) {  // redirect if validation fails, note the ->withErrors($validator)

        return redirect()
            ->route('your.route')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }

 // Do other stuff if no error

}
```

And, in the view you can handle errors like this:

```
 <div class="<?php if (count($errors) > 0) { echo 'alert alert-danger'; } ?>" >

    <ul>
        @if (count($errors) > 0)
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{!! $error !!}</li>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    </ul>
</div>
```

And if you want the input data, you need to redirect with `->withInput();` which can be fetch in view like:

**Update**

```
 <input name= "job_title" value="{{ Request::old('job_title') }}" />
```

But, the best thing is to use laravel `Form` package so they all are handled automatically.

Comment: I already get $error message array but I need Data array which one I show in image 

I already used this code view code for error array

Comment: see my updated answer. does that helps? I guess you want to retain the submitted data on occurrence of error?

Comment: can explain little bit more @VipindasKS

Comment: see the line in my answer         `return redirect()
            ->route('your.route')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();`  this will redirect the form without losing the form field values. so you can call it in your fields like <input value="{{ Request::old('job_title') }}" />

Comment: Again, this is in assumption that you need to show the form fields filled with already submitted data, when some of the fields fails validation. so that, you don't need to fill it again.

Comment: @MuhammadBilal Glad that it helped. Try to use Form packages for building forms, so that yo will never want to call like `value="{{ Request::old('job_title') }}"`

Answer (score 0):

If you just need form data, you can use Request object:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
 {
     $name = $request->input('firstName');
 }
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#accessing-the-request

Alternatively, you could use `$request->get('firstName');`

Answer (score 0):

Use `old()` to get previous value from input. Example:

```
<input name="firstName" value="{{old('firstName')}}">
```

See documentation here https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#old-input